# Not displaying sections with javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display a calendar on the homepage and have staff add their birthdays to the calendar but it's not displaying the dates, duration and Name section.

Here is the code for the homepage (excluding css files etc.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .row > .column {
        padding: 0 8px;
    }

    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: black;
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 1200px;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .mySlides {
        display: none;
    }

    .cursor {
        cursor: pointer
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev,
    .next {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: auto;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

  /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        .prev:hover,
        .next:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }

    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    img {
        margin-bottom: -4px;
    }

    .caption-container {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 2px 16px;
        color: white;
    }

    .demo {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

        .active,
        .demo:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    img.hover-shadow {
        transition: 0.3s
    }

    .hover-shadow:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <nav align="center">
        <br /><img src="images/logo.png" /><br /><br />
        <a href="home.html">Home  |  </a>
        <a href="meeting.html">Create Meeting  |  </a>
        <a href="#join">Join Meeting</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfix"><br /><br /></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <br /><img src="images/img6.jpg" align="right" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/img4.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides" align="center">
                <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                <br /><br /><img src="images/img6.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>


            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

            <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"></p>
            </div>


            <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <br /><br /><img class="demo cursor" src="images/img6.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="" align="middle">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openModal() {
            document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeModal() {
            document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
        }

        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
            if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
            if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
            captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
        }
    </script>

    <section align="left">
        <img src="images/hdsplitter.png" align="middle" /><br /><br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;<h1 style="color:#0099ff">Welcome to <b>Systeque</b></h1>
        <br />
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">                
            <div align="left">
                <br />
                <h3 style="color:#0099ff"><b>Who We Are</b></h3>
                <p><b style="color:#0099ff">Systeque</b> was established in 1998 and has grown to be one of South Africa's leading IT Solution and Service Providers. Systeque is based in the Hyde Park, Sandton in Johannesburg. Systeque’s core focus is to provide total solutions to all customers by bringing new and innovative concepts and cost effective ideas to market. Our strengths lie in Infrastructure Architecture, Cloud Computing and Managed Services. Since inception, Systeque has developed in areas that have shown a definite market requirement. With implementations in all business sectors.</p>
                <br /><h3 style="color:#0099ff"><b>My role at the Company</b></h3>
                <p>As Operations Manager my duties include co-ordination of our technical team to ensure daily operational functions of the business are running, this also entails ensuring the sales function of the business is processing quotations and orders in accordance with client requirements. Client relations being one of my key areas involves consulting with clients on their daily requirements and projects they are running or planning. Other vital areas of my role includes continous research into products, services and technologies that will further streamline our processes and grow our revenue.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <img src="images/img5.jpg" alt="service" width="450" />
                <br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </section>  
    <section align="center">
        <h1 style="color:#0099ff"><b>Calender</b></h1>
    </section>
</div>
```

And here is the code for the Assignment page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type ="text/javascript">

var celebration = new Array();  
var months = new Array(12);
var times = new Array(9);
var duration = new Array(9);
var attends = new Array();
var mNum, yNum, dNum, smon, sdate, dif, stimes, sdur;
var Cname, Cmonth, Cdate, Ctime, Cduration, Cvenue, Cnum, Crefresh;

function upDate()
{
    document.f1.date.length = 0;        
    var j;
    var mSel = document.f1.month.selectedIndex;
    mSel = mSel + mNum;

    if((mSel>11) && (mSel<=14))
    {
        mSel = mSel - 12;
    }

    if((mSel===0) || (mSel==2) || (mSel==4) || (mSel==6) || (mSel==7) || (mSel==9) || (mSel==11))
    {
        j = 31;
    }
    else if((mSel==3) || (mSel==5) || (mSel==8) || (mSel==10))
    {
        j = 30;
    }
    else if(mSel==1)
    {
        if((yNum%4)===0)
        {
            j = 29;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 28;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error with system time");
    }

    for(var i=0; i<j; i++)
    {
        var opt = new Option(i+1, i+1, false, false);
        document.f1.date.options[i] = opt;
    }

    if(document.f1.month.selectedIndex===0)
    {
        for(i=(dNum-1); i>=0; i--)
        {
            document.f1.date.options[i] = null;
        }

        if(document.f1.date.length===0)
        {
            document.f1.month.options[0].disabled = true;
            document.f1.month.selectedIndex = 1;
            upDate();
        }
    }

    if(document.f1.month.selectedIndex==3)
    {
        document.f1.date.length = 0;
        var dn = dNum;
        if(dn>j)
        {
            dn = j;
        }

        for(;i<dn; i++)
        {
            var opt = new Option(i+1, i+1, false, false);
            document.f1.date.options[i] = opt;
        }
    }
    capture();
}

function validate()
{
    capture();

    if(Cname==="")
    {
        alert("Celebration cannot be created - Name required");
        document.f1.n.focus();
    }
    else if(Cnum==="")
    {
        alert("Celebration cannot be created - Description required");
        document.f1.num.focus();
    }
    else if(Cvenue==="")
    {
        alert("Celebration cannot be created - Venue required");
        document.f1.ven.focus();
    }
    else
    {
        bookCelebration();
    }
}

function capture()
{
    Cname = document.f1.n.value;
    Cnum = document.f1.num.value;

    Cmonth = document.f1.month.selectedIndex;
    Cmonth = document.f1.month.options[Cmonth].value;
    Cmonth = months[Cmonth];

    Cdate = document.f1.date.selectedIndex;
    Cdate = document.f1.date.options[Cdate].value;

    Ctime = document.f1.time.selectedIndex;
    Ctime = document.f1.time.options[Ctime].value;

    Cduration = document.f1.dur.selectedIndex;
    Cduration = document.f1.dur.options[Cduration].value;

    Cvenue = document.f1.ven.value;

    if(document.f1.refresh.checked === true)
    {
        Crefresh = "true";
    }
    else
    {
        Crefresh = "false";
    }       
}

function bookMeeting()
{
    var index = meetings.length;
    meetings[index] = new Array(8);

    celebration[index][0] = Cname;
    celebration[index][1] = Cnum;
    celebration[index][2] = Cmonth;
    celebration[index][3] = Cdate;
    celebration[index][4] = Ctime;
    celebration[index][5] = Cduration;
    celebration[index][6] = Cvenue;
    celebration[index][7] = Crefresh;

    addBooking(index);
}

function addBooking(index)
{
    var opt = new Option(Cname, Cnum, Cmonth, Cdate, Ctime, Cduration, Cvenue, Crefresh);
    document.f2.nm.options[index] = opt;
    alert("Booking successful");
    clearInput();

    if(celebration.length===0)
    {
        document.f2.v.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.f2.v.disabled = false;
    }
}

function search()
{
    var inp = document.f2.nm.selectedIndex;
    var pos;
    inp = celebration[inp][0];

    for(var i=0; i<celebration.length; i++)
    {
        if (inp==celebration[i][0])
        {
            pos = i;
        }
    }

    document.f1.n.value = celebration[pos][0];
    document.f1.num.value = celebration[pos][1];

    smon = celebration[pos][2];
    for (var j=0; j<months.length; j++)
    {
        if(months[j] == smon)
        {
            smon = j;
        }
    }
    smon = smon - mNum;
    document.f1.month.selectedIndex = smon;

    upDate();
    sdate = celebration[pos][3];
    if (smon===0)
    {
        dif = sdate - dNum;
        dif = dif -1;
    }
    else
    {
        dif = sdate - 1;
    }   
    document.f1.date.selectedIndex = dif;

    stimes = celebration[pos][4];
    for (; j<times.length; j++)
    {
        if(times[j] == stimes)
        {
            stimes = j;
        }
    }
    document.f1.time.selectedIndex = stimes;

    sdur = celebration[pos][5];
    for (; j<duration.length; j++)
    {
        if(duration[j] == sdur)
        {
            sdur = j;
        }
    }
    document.f1.dur.selectedIndex = sdur;

    document.f1.ven.value = celebration[pos][6];

    if(celebration[pos][7]=="true")
    {
        document.f1.refresh.checked = true;
    }
    else if(celebration[pos][7]=="false")
    {   
        document.f1.refresh.checked = false;
    }

    document.f2.join.disabled = false

}

function joinCelebration()
{
    var index = attends.length;
    attends[index] = new Array(5);
    attends[index][0] = window.prompt("Enter first name");
    attends[index][1] = window.prompt("Enter surname");
    attends[index][2] = window.prompt("Enter email address");
    attends[index][3] = window.prompt("Enter office number");   
    attends[index][4] = window.prompt("Enter celebration name");

    var x = document.f2.nm.selectedIndex;
    attends[index][4] = document.f2.nm.options[x].value;
    y = attends[index][4];
    var nat = 0;
    for(var a=0; a<attends.length;a++)
    {
        if(attends[a][4] = y)
        {
            nat = nat +1;
        }
    }
    document.f3.atnd.value = nat;

    var g = celebration[index][5];
    var drt;
    for (var h=0; h<duration.length; h++)
    {
        if(duration[h] == g)
        {
            drt = h;
        }
    }

    if(drt < 2)
    {
        document.f3.sgref.value = "Tea & Biscuits";
    }
    else if(drt < 4)
    {
        document.f3.sgref.value = "Finger Lunch";
    }
    else
    {
        document.f3.sgref.value = "Sit down Lunch";
    }

    clearInput();

}   


function popMonths()
{   
    months[1] = "January";
    months[2] = "February";
    months[3] = "March";
    months[4] = "April";
    months[5] = "May";
    months[6] = "June";
    months[7] = "July";
    months[8] = "August";
    months[9] = "September";
    months[10] = "October";
    months[11] = "November";
    months[12] = "December";

}

function popDuration()
{   
    duration[0] = "30 mins";
    duration[1] = "1 hour";
    duration[2] = "2 hours";
    duration[3] = "3 hours";
    duration[4] = "4 hours";
    duration[5] = "5 hours";
    duration[6] = "6 hours";
    duration[7] = "7 hours";
    duration[8] = "8 hours";
}

function curDate()
{
    var now = new Date();
    mNum = now.getMonth();
    yNum = now.getFullYear();
    dNum = now.getDate();
}

function updateMonth()
{
    var opt1 = new Option(months[mNum], mNum, false, false);
    document.f1.month.options[0] = opt1;

    var opt2 = new Option(months[mNum + 1], mNum + 1, false, false);
    document.f1.month.options[1] = opt2;

    var opt3 = new Option(months[mNum + 2], mNum + 2, false, false);
    document.f1.month.options[2] = opt3;

    var opt4 = new Option(months[mNum + 3], mNum + 3, false, false);
    document.f1.month.options[3] = opt4;
}

function upDate()
{
    document.f1.date.length = 0;        
    var j;
    var mSel = document.f1.month.selectedIndex;
    mSel = mSel + mNum;

    if((mSel>11) && (mSel<=14))
    {
        mSel = mSel - 12;
    }

    if((mSel===0) || (mSel==2) || (mSel==4) || (mSel==6) || (mSel==7) || (mSel==9) || (mSel==11))
    {
        j = 31;
    }
    else if((mSel==3) || (mSel==5) || (mSel==8) || (mSel==10))
    {
        j = 30;
    }
    else if(mSel==1)
    {
        if((yNum%4)===0)
        {
            j = 29;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 28;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error with system time");
    }

    for(var i=0; i<j; i++)
    {
        var opt = new Option(i+1, i+1, false, false);
        document.f1.date.options[i] = opt;
    }

    if(document.f1.month.selectedIndex===0)
    {
        for(i=(dNum-1); i>=0; i--)
        {
            document.f1.date.options[i] = null;
        }

        if(document.f1.date.length===0)
        {
            document.f1.month.options[0].disabled = true;
            document.f1.month.selectedIndex = 1;
            upDate();
        }
    }

    if(document.f1.month.selectedIndex==3)
    {
        document.f1.date.length = 0;
        var dn = dNum;
        if(dn>j)
        {
            dn = j;
        }

        for(; i<dn; i++)
        {
            var opt = new Option(i+1, i+1, false, false);
            document.f1.date.options[i] = opt;
        }
    }
    capture();
}

function popTimes()
{
    times[0] = "8:00am";
    times[1] = "9:00am";
    times[2] = "10:00am";
    times[3] = "11:00am";
    times[4] = "12:00pm";
    times[5] = "1:00pm";
    times[6] = "2:00pm";
    times[7] = "3:00pm";
    times[8] = "4:00pm";
}

function upTimes()
{
    for(var i=0; i<times.length; i++)
    {
        var opt = new Option(times[i]);
        document.f1.time.options[i] = opt;
    }
}

function upDur()
{
    for(var i=0; i<duration.length; i++)
    {
        var opt = new Option(duration[i]);
        document.f1.dur.options[i] = opt;
    }
}

function clearInput()
{
    initialize();
    document.f1.n.value = "";
    document.f1.num.value = "";
    document.f1.ven.value = "";
    document.f1.refresh.checked = false;

}   

function initialize()
{
    popMonths();
    popTimes();
    curDate();
    popDuration();
    updateMonth();
    upDate();
    upTimes();
    upDur();
    document.f1.n.focus();

    if(celebration.length===0)
    {
        document.f2.v.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.f2.v.disabled = false;
    }
}

</script>
</head>


<body onload = "initialize()">
<form name = "f1">
<h1> Create a celebration </h1>
<table border = "0" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td>
    Birthday of
    <input type = "text" name = "n"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>
    Birthday Message
    <input type = "text" name = "num" onchange = "capture()"/>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
    Date: Month
    <select name = "month" onchange = "upDate()"/>
        <option value = "0">
            Nothing
        </option>
    </select>   
</td>

<td>
    Date
    <select name = "date" onchange = "capture()"/>
        <option value = "0">
            Nothing
        </option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>
    Time
    <select name = "time" onchange = "capture()"/>
        <option value = "0">
            Nothing
        </option>

    </select>   
</td>

<td>
    Duration
    <select name = "dur" onchange = "capture()"/>
        <option value = "0">
            Nothing
        </option>

    </select>   
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    Venue
    <input type = "text" name = "ven" onchange = "capture()"/>
</td>

<td>
    Refreshments
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "refresh" onchange = "capture()" onclick = "capture()"/>    
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align = "center">
    <input type = "button" value = "Create" onclick = "validate()"/>
</td>

<td align = "right">
    <input type = "button" name = "del" value = "Delete" disabled = "true" onclick = "deleteBooking()"/>

    <input type = "button" value = "Clear" onclick = "clearInput()"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<form name = "f2">
<h1> Sign-up for celebration </h1>
<table border = "0" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td>
    Name
    <select name = "nm"/>
        <option value = "0">
        None
        </option>
    </select>   
</td>


</tr>

<tr>
<td align = "center">
    <input type = "button" value = "Search" name = "v"onclick = "search()"/>
</td>

<td align = "center">
    <input type = "button" name = "join" value = "Join" disabled = "true"/ onclick = "joinCelebration()">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<form name = "f3">
<h1>Celebration details</h1>
<table border = "0" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td>
    Number of attendees
    <input type = "text" name = "atnd"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>
    Suggested refreshments
    <input type = "text" name = "sgref"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When you click on any dropdown it says "nothing" instead of the options.

Comment: can you create a snippet/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

this probably because you are missing the jquery file. jquery is a must when you used bootstrap. have you check the Starter template here: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - the reason the dropdowns were not showing the options from the JavaScript code was because testing against 0 needs to have ===.

```
 if((mSel===0) || (mSel==2) || (mSel==4) || (mSel==6) || (mSel==7) || (mSel==9) || (mSel==11))
{
```

Now however the calander does not show on the home page. The assignment page needs to be a page to create birthday celebrations for staff members and the home page must have calendar showing links to celebrations that have already been created.

That is the main thing so it needs capture and show it.